# angularjs can't save chacked chekbox in edit page when get value from rest

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, rest

This is a part of my code from modal of edit data

```
<div  class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <div  ng-controller="admin">
        <label ng-repeat="(key,val) in dataFromCompanies.Response.companies"  >
            <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="managerEdit.companies" checklist-value="val" />
                   {{ val.name }}+ {{val.id}}
        </label>
        <span ng-repeat="(key,val) in managerEdit.companies">{{val.id}}</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide more information or a more specific question. Do you have errors? Is the behavoir unexpected? What did you expect? What is happening? I working (or broken) code snippet would also be helpful.

Comment: I haven't errors,  i get values from rest successful , when i use one check box everything   is ok, but when we have check list chekboxes ara not cheked

Comment: Please show us your controller code in which you get some value from REST.

Comment: Please provide more information. What is exactly the problem? Show us your controller or service or directive handling your checkbox so we're able to see what is going on